# How to add a dll in reference of Visual Studio 2017 permanently for all users?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Every time my colleague writes a code that requires a particular dll as a reference, he has to add reference in VS 2017. Can this dll be permanently added to the reference so that all the users like him can use that dll and don't have to add reference everythime?

Comment: How about NuGet packages?

Comment: How about creating a custom project template?

Comment: I am new to Visual Studio 2017. I am not a coder but system administrator. Please suggest how that NuGet or custom template can be applied to the mentioned scenario?

Comment: Try [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017).